# After migrating to vs2013/.NET 4.5 WPF UIs starting to have visual glitches

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, visual-glitch

I have recently upgraded to visual studio 2013 and .NET 4.5 from vc9 and .NET3.5. We have been noticing a lot of visual glitches in the user interface. Some panels are losing their background color - then when you click on them a refresh happens and they are fine. When moving a window from one screen to another a whole bunch of visual glitches occur.

These issues were not happening before we upgraded. I've searched around trying to see if this is a common problem - no luck so far. I thought originally that it had something to do with applying styles, but it seems to happen even on unstyled controls - even a form with just a tabcontrol and no other controls causes this.  I have an application that opens the following window. There are no styles, no themes applied, no code behind, nothing. Yet I still sometimes get glitches like you see in the first snapshot. They are not always the same glitches.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" TabStripPlacement="Top" Background="White">
            <TabItem  Header="tab 1dfgdfgdfg">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="tab 2">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This happens on most computers, we have not detected a pattern of graphics cards, or systems. I am using vs 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Has anyone seen this problem? More importantly, has anyone resolved this problem?

[image]

[image: Tab Control header]

[image: Tabcontrol border]

[image: losing the background color]

Comment: It would be useful if you told us all of the things you have researched and tried so far, since cycling through things you've already tried makes us sad.  Did you try `UseLayoutRounding`, as described on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613588(v=vs.100).aspx), for example?

Comment: Close-Voted. Upgrade from what? what have you tried? Are you using third party controls? where's your XAML? Does it happen on all computers? Why do I have to ask all this instead of it being part of the question already?

Comment: LayoutRounding is generally for geometry objects, but it was worth a try. No that doesn't appear to fix the issues.  As I said, this happens even for the most basic of layouts, with no styles, no themes no nothing.

Comment: The XAML you have posted is not valid? Where is the real markup? Surely you have at least "xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" defined?

Comment: Not that I imagine this will help anyone, I have included the WHOLE xaml code.  The code is doing almost nothing.  This is why this problem is so perplexing.

Comment: @Liz Yes i can confirm that nothing in the posted xaml is a problem. Its looks to be working fine. Assuming the MainWindow is being instantiated through the App.xaml StartupUri or similar there might be style overrides in the App.xaml perhaps? Sorry but theres a lot of info missing.

Comment: Does this occur only in your own app, or does a very basic app (containing only the XAML you posted and no code behind) exhibit the same issues? If this is in a corporate environment, look for commonalities across the problematic machines. I have seen similar issues from incompatible video card drivers (which you mentioned you checked) to virus scanners. Assuming that a very basic app breaks, you need to be looking at something in the environment- I can assure you this isn't normal.